# Is robustness to interruption related to the ability to multi-task?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, reference-request

Is the ability to resume a task effectively after an interruption related to a person's ability to multi-task? The only theory of multi-tasking I'm aware of is [PRIMs which models multi-tasking as being limited by over-lapping neural resources](http://www.ai.rug.nl/~niels/multitasking.html). I'm also assuming that a person's ability to resume a task is an attribute that varies across populations, but would appreciate references providing evidence for or against this.